# Can't create the initial database with Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

When I try to run it

```
>> from app.py import db
>> db.create_all()
```

[image]
[image]

Above is the complete error message
I have found in the Task Manager, the postgresql service is on.
The database password is correct and I can't find where the error is.
My computer is Win10 and I installed postgresql using the official installer

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using other tools (psql, pgAdmin)? If not, then it'll likely be a postgresql configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

replace the word database with the name of your database

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/database'
```

by default, your database name is likely 'postgres', you also need to provide your port number, default is 5432.
Try using the following:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
```